# EC2 instance not listing all of the CloudWatch Metrics AWS shows on examples

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I created an EC2 instance, and we're adding Cloudwatch so we can add monitoring abilities to our servers, we're in the testing/learning phase, But now that i'm adding some metrics i' ve noticed that i do only have available 37 metrics for this EC2 instance, when you check this tutorial:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html

It clearly shows that there are 316 metrics by default On EC2

We previously identified some metrics that we want to inspect on our servers and when i tried to add them into the Dashboard i noticed they are just a few in comparison with the picture on the tutorial i 've shown above.

- Enabled detailed monitoring
- Configured the Agent on the Linux (Ubuntu instance)
- Pull the metrics via Amazon Cli to verify the qty of available metrics for me and it returns the same 37
- I added Full Control to Cloudwatch on the role i'm currently using for this EC2 instance

Any feedback, suggestion or comment will be highly appreciated,

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That screenshot indicates that there 316 metrics available in that particular account.

[image: CloudWatch metrics]

This could be 79 instances with 4 metrics each, or any combination of instances and metrics. It does *not* mean there are 316 metrics for *each* instance.

Comment: Thanks John Rotenstein i got confused somehow so i misunderstood  that tutorial somehow, but thanks for clarifying it means that there are only 37 metrics available by default and you start adding your as you go. so happy cause i'm in the right path right now, appreciate your comment.